# How can i add a border to flutter container with child size instead of parent size?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can i add a border to flutter container with child size instead of parent size?

Current layout

[image: Current layout]

Desired layout

[image: Desired layout]

Code

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0XFF136154),
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // Child
        // Login Text
        // Email feild
        // Password feild
        // Login Button
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you include from scaffold body, child size is controlled by parent widget in flutter

Comment: return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0XFF136154),
      body: Container(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The height of the Column is determined by the mainAxisSize property

I think it is missing

```dart
Column(
   mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize.min
```

default is `MainAxisSize.max,`

Another thing is needed to be done, using `Center` widget on `body`

```dart
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0XFF136154),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, // this is by default
          children: [
            // Child
            // Login Text
            // Email feild
            // Password feild
            // Login Button
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: you can use padding to have some space between column

Comment: Thanks! that worked. But horizontal borders are still touching edges of screen. How to center those too?

Comment: Can i give padding universally, or should i wrap padding to each children?

Comment: you can wrap your column with padding